# Angular Factory not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The controller isn't picking up the data correctly from the factory for it to display in the view (or the factory syntax isn't correct for the controller). I initially had all the data in the controller and it worked fine but when I transferred it into the factory the data would no longer display on the view. So either the controller isnt calling the factory data correctly or the factory isnt defined correctly, and I don't know which one is wrong.

Contoller:

```
app.controller('dbCtrl', ['$scope', 'myfactory', function($scope, myfactory) {
 myfactory.success(function(data) {

$scope.test1 = results[0].data;
$scope.test2 = results[1].data;
$scope.test3 = results[2].data;

});
}]);
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('myfactory', ['$http', function($http, $q) { 

$q.all([
$http.get('/url1'),
$http.get('/url2'),
$http.get('/url3')   
]).then(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 

 }]);
```

Comment: All you have to tell us now is what the actual problem is.

Comment: alright, I've reworded my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code syntax for creating and accessing factory is wrong. you should check [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

But to your problem, I have created example matching yours. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TJObJN?p=preview

```
myfactory.getResult().then(function(results) {
....  
}   
 app.factory('myfactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {

  var _getResult = function() {

    // returns promise which depends on all 3 http responses.
    // parallel AJAX request.
    return $q.all([ 
      $http.get('/url1'),
      $http.get('/url2'),
      $http.get('/url3')
    ]);

  };

  // public functions available in controller 
  return {
    getResult: _getResult
  };

  ///////////////////
}]);
```

few notes:

1. Angular factory you create should return Object containing functions or properties.
2. make sure you add all dependancies in array as well as in function arguments.
3. $q promise only has then. while $http promise gives success(...) callback.
   Check out syntax and examples here

Comment: thats awesome, thanks for the informative answer its helped me understand factories heaps better!

Answer (score 1):

```
app.factory('myfactory', ['$http', function($http, $q) { 
    return {
        getAll: $q.all([
            $http.get('/url1'),
            $http.get('/url2'),
            $http.get('/url3')   
        ]).
        then(function(data) { 
            return data; 
        });
    };
}]);
```

And then in ctrl:

```
myfactory.getAll().then( ...
```

Comment: great, so would the ctrl be:
      
myfactory.getAll().then(function(data) { 
 $scope.network = results[0].data;
$scope.blog = results[1].data;
$scope.network_all = results[2].data;
  });